# How can I make this component (Toggle Button, Android-Java)?

Tags: java, android

I can't find this component in the material design documentation and I'd like to know how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen it as a pre-built component, maybe someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

But replicating it would be fairly simple.

2 `Buttons` and a `ConstraintLayout`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="Sign In" />

    <Button
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:id="@+id/register_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Register" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >
```

You will have to tweak it for your use case but this should be like 90% of what you need. You may also have to create a custom button to get that more rounded shape. This is an older tutorial on how to customize buttons it should still be relevant. https://www.codebrainer.com/blog/13-designs-for-buttons-every-android-beginner-should-know